# How to move text dynamically in the TextView with fixed width?

Tags: android, android-widget

I write calculator application. The source code is:

```
TextView display = new TextView (this);
display.setMaxLines(1);
```

When user calculates a long expression , he sees in the "display" only the beginning of this expression and doesn't see its end. I can change the code in order to show, for example, the last 20 typed by user signs in the "display", but I look for some other solution like

```
tv.set?? (?? )
```

in order to move text dynamically to left direction in the "display". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ellipsize to marquee and the text view will scroll automatically when longer.

Comment: Hi Manfred, thanks! It works excellent. I just wanted to add that I also set to true setSelected.